# Use of functions between inner object literals in javascript

Tags: javascript

My issue is I have 2 inner objects in my js class and I'm trying to use the methods from one of those objects in my other object (examples of what I'm trying to do below). I understand why this doesn't work because of a the scope. I'm just wondering if there is a way to get it to work.

```
var Class1 = {

    self : this,
    Obj1 : {

        Obj1Method : function () {
            alert("Do something");
        },
        Obj1Method2 : function () {
            alert("Do something else");
        },

        InnerObj1 : {
            InnerNestObj1Method : function (val) {
                alert(val + 2);
            }
        }
    },

    Class1Method2 : function () {
        this.Obj1.Obj1Method2();
    },

    Obj2 : {

        Obj2Method : function (val2) {
            self.Obj1.InnerObj1.InnerNestObj1Method(val2);
        },

        Obj2Method2 : function () {
            self.Class1Method2();
        }
    }
};

Class1.Obj1.InnerObj1.InnerNestObj1Method(3); //works
Class1.Class1Method2(); //works
Class1.Obj2.Obj2Method2(); //No bueno
Class1.Obj2.Obj2Method(5); //No bueno
```

Comment: The value of the `self` property will **not** be a reference to `Class1`.  It's whatever the value of `this` is *outside* the object initializer.

Comment: @Liam `this` is not the function.

Comment: As noted by Pointy, `self : this` without a funciton scope gives you whatever `this` is outside the object, most likely `self` is the same as `window`.

Comment: You need to use `Class1` for `self`. `self` is outsite when you call the function you need so you got the `window` (like `this`)

Comment: Note that there is no inheritance here

Comment: Yeah I realized I labeled it wrong after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix your example by replacing `self` with `Class1`.
The line `self : this,` is setting `Class1.self` to point to the global object (`this` when that line is evaluated).

```js
var Class1 = {

    self : this,
    Obj1 : {

        Obj1Method : function () {
            alert("Do something");
        },
        Obj1Method2 : function () {
            alert("Do something else");
        },

        InnerObj1 : {
            InnerNestObj1Method : function (val) {
                alert(val + 2);
            }
        }
    },

    Class1Method2 : function () {
        this.Obj1.Obj1Method2();
    },

    Obj2 : {

        Obj2Method : function (val2) {
            Class1.Obj1.InnerObj1.InnerNestObj1Method(val2);
        },

        Obj2Method2 : function () {
            Class1.Class1Method2();
        }
    }
};

Class1.Obj1.InnerObj1.InnerNestObj1Method(3); //works
Class1.Class1Method2(); //works
Class1.Obj2.Obj2Method2(); //bueno
Class1.Obj2.Obj2Method(5); //bueno
```

What happens when you do `self: this`

```
// If this is running in non strict mode, from the global scope, `this` points
// To the global object because there was no function call setting `this`
var Class1 = {
    self : this,
};
```

What you need to understand is that `this` is set by whoever called the function using `this`. In the example above, there is no caller, so the runtime sets `this` to point to the global object.

Here's how you could you could make your object a bit more reusable and give yourself a reference to the outer object:

```js
function createClass() {
  var self = {
    Obj1: {

      Obj1Method: function() {
        alert("Do something");
      },
      Obj1Method2: function() {
        alert("Do something else");
      },

      InnerObj1: {
        InnerNestObj1Method: function(val) {
          alert(val + 2);
        }
      }
    },

    Class1Method2: function() {
      self.Obj1.Obj1Method2();
    },

    Obj2: {

      Obj2Method: function(val2) {
        self.Obj1.InnerObj1.InnerNestObj1Method(val2);
      },

      Obj2Method2: function() {
        self.Class1Method2();
      }
    }
  };
  return self;
}

var Class1 = createClass();

Class1.Obj1.InnerObj1.InnerNestObj1Method(3); //works
Class1.Class1Method2(); //works
Class1.Obj2.Obj2Method2(); //works
Class1.Obj2.Obj2Method(5); //works
```

Comment: Thanks taught me something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
"use strict"
class Class1 {
  constructor() {
    this.Obj1 = {
      Obj1Method: function() {
        alert("Do something");
      },
      Obj1Method2: function() {
        alert("Do something else");
      },

      InnerObj1: {
        InnerNestObj1Method: function(val) {
          alert(val + 2);
        }
      }
    };
    
    var self = this;
    this.Obj2 = {
      Obj2Method: function(val2) {
        self.Obj1.InnerObj1.InnerNestObj1Method(val2);
      },

      Obj2Method2: function() {
        self.Class1Method2();
      }
    };
  }

  Class1Method2() {
    this.Obj1.Obj1Method2();
  }

};

var c1 = new Class1();
c1.Obj1.InnerObj1.InnerNestObj1Method(3); //works
c1.Class1Method2(); //works
c1.Obj2.Obj2Method(3); //works
c1.Obj2.Obj2Method2(); //works
```